# How to .Clone div without cloning the wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to clone the content of a div without copying the div itself with it?

I use this function, but it copies div-1 inside div-2.

```
$(function(){
    var $div = $('.div-1').clone();
    $('.div-2').html($div);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="div-2">
</div>
<div class="div-2">
</div>
```

GOAL:

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="div-2">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="div-2">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the children elements using:

```
 $(function(){
  var $div = $(".div-1").children().clone(true,true);
  $('.div-2').html($div);
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zf748beo/)**

Comment: Does this clone all content, even on deeper levels, including text?

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone he children

```
$(function(){
    var $div = $('.div-1').children().clone();
    $('.div-2').html($div);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div-2').html($('.div-1').html());
```

Try this it will work